# Автологин в Linux (Debian) стоит опасаться?

Tags: debian, авторизация

Надоело каждый раз вводить пароль при входе в систему (Debian, XFCE/lightdm) и решил в файл  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` добавить:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=user
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Но возник вопрос, с точки зрения безопасности чем это грозит. Если не предвидится физического доступа к компьютеру постороннего *(хотя пароль при входе точно не будет помехой, если будет физический доступ)*.

Comment: честно пытаюсь понять, причём тут дистрибутив *debian* вообще и программа *linux* в частности. пока безуспешно. помогите, пожалуйста, вас понять (дополнив текст вопроса после нажатия [edit]).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в качестве рабочей операционной системы я использую Debian. Каждый раз при запуске системы выскакивает окно в которое надо ввести логин и пароль. Я хочу использовать вместо этого автологин, вот и хотелось бы узнать с точки зрения безопасности.

Comment: Т.е. вы думаете,  автологин  как-то влияет на безопасность? И если влияет то, на какую, по вашему мнению, безопасность, он влияет, на что?